# Recyclerview not displaying when recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true); is added

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm pulling data from firebase into a recyclerview. When I add the recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true); my app doesnt crash but nothing appears. When I get rid of this line my data appears but all the content in touching and the cardview is shrinking to suit the data. Is there any solutions to this?
Edit:
This is the CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventParent"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bgitemcustom"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/crash" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/make"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="Mercedes"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="Saloon"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="2004"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/connect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Connect"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is where i am creating the recylerview. Its the first one i'm using with the id:eventsplace:

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"

        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/eventsplace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingRight="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/contacts"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/contacts"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="368dp"
       android:text="Contacts"
       android:textColor="@color/yellow"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/contacts"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventsplace"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contacts"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Add your layout.

Comment: added them there

Comment: Are you getting all data from Firebase at once?

Comment: Try it with a getChildrenQuery. It might help

Comment: Set the height of your `CardView` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Yeah im getting all data from firebase at once.

Comment: im using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: I fixed the spacing between the by adding layout margin to the card view but the cards are still half the size they are meant to be

Comment: fixed it i set the card view width to wrap content. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

After trying out different approaches, the issue is because the item layout does not fit within the recycler layout.

Here are  a few solutions :

1. Set the height of your CardView to `wrap_content`
2. Set a fixed height for the layout_height of recycler view in constraint layout instead of `wrap_content`